# How do I unset session products in shopping cart using remove button?

Tags: javascript, php, session, shopping-cart

How do I unset session products in a shopping cart using a remove button? I have the below code; 'clear cart' is working and unsets the session for all items from the shopping. But the problem is that 'remove' doesn't unset single products through pid?

**Php**:

```
session_start();

$pid=$_SESSION['pid'];

function remove_product($pid){
  $pid=intval($pid);
  $max=count($_SESSION['product1']);

  for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){

    if($pid==$_SESSION['product1'][$i]['pid']){
      unset($_SESSION['product1'][$i]);
      break;
    }

  }

  $_SESSION['product1']=array_values($_SESSION['product1']);

}

if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
  remove_product($_REQUEST['product1'][$pid]);
}

if($_REQUEST['command']=='clear' && isset($_REQUEST['remove'])){
  unset($_SESSION['image12']);
  unset($_SESSION['product1']);
  unset($_SESSION['price12']);
  unset($_SESSION['itemcode3']);
  unset($_SESSION['sizes12']);
}
```

**Js**:

```
function del(pid){

  if(confirm('Do you really mean to delete this item')){
    document.form1.pid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='delete';
    document.form1.submit();
  }

}

function clear_cart(){

  if(confirm('This will empty your shopping cart, continue?')){
    document.form1.command.value='clear';
    document.form1.submit();
  }

}
```

**Html:**

```
<form  name="form1" method="post">  

  <input type="hidden" name="pid" />
  <input type="hidden" name="command" />  

  <input type="button" class="button2" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()" />

  <a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $pid?>)">
    <input type="button" class="button2" value="Remove" />
  </a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
remove_product($_REQUEST['product1'][$pid]);
}
```

is no $_REQUEST['product1'] in your form,
maybe

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
```

$_REQUEST['remove'] also

Comment: joe lee then it should be `$_SESSION['product1']` instead of `$_REQUEST['product1']`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='clear' && isset($_REQUEST['remove'])){
unset($_SESSION['image12']);
unset($_SESSION['product1']);
unset($_SESSION['price12']);
unset($_SESSION['itemcode3']);
unset($_SESSION['sizes12']);
}
```

I don't see any $_REQUEST['remove'] to be sent.

Your clear command also don't send $pid, isn't it necessary?

In fact, clear() sends query string `pid=&command=clear`

Comment: so what is the solution now?

Comment: What do you mean with $_REQUEST['remove'] if you try to check if both clear or remove buttons are clicked, it seems like not proper check? What do you want to be checked before the unset() starts? i.e. if `pid` is sent and `clear` is clicked?